# Converting 1D to 2D?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

This might seem like a stupid question but it's really bugging me.

Basically, I have a 1D array that I need to convert into a 2D array. Basically, the size of the array is: 62017 now from this, I need to get the Rows and Cols of this. But, do this dynamically, so for example, it would take the number of say: 43101 and then establish the rows+cols and then re-size the vector accordingly.

I hope I've explained enough and hope someone can help, thanks :)

Comment: 62017 is prime, you cannot evenly split it into rows and columns.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.. Is there any way around it? I need to make it into an even number, basically, the vector contain's 0's so removing these 0's may decrease the size?

Comment: 43101, on the other hand, could be split either as `3x14367` or `9x4789`. You need to provide the size of at least one dimension.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to split a 1D matrix into 2D blocks of equal size. The algorithm that I have takes in a 2D matrix and I need the W+H in order for the algorithm to work!

Comment: This could certainly be done.  If you want to ensure there are no "empty" cells, and dynmaically calculate this, you'll sometimes just end up with "2D Arrays" that are only 1-wide.  @user1582478 Are you looking for the exact code to produce this?

Comment: I think if you want an answer, you are going to have to be more descriptive (sample pseudo-code is helpful). Also, is this homework?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way around prime numbers not having factors? Like, "I know, but can I factorize it anyway"?

Comment: Hey, this isn't homework. I'm doing this for a project and wanting some help. Hey @MartyE I'm going to be cheeky and ask for a code example, because I just don't know where to start with it. I just need to be able to split a massive block of data into a 2D vector.

Comment: @user1582478  Hmm, keep in mind asking for the code samples is asking a lot (should definitely upvote and accept anyone that posts a correct answer, maybe even a bounty if you really want it).  I'll see if I can get it before heading off to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here it is old school array style (since I can't access a C++0x compiler at the moment)

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <array>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

void calc_new_sizes(const size_t old_size, size_t& new_size1, size_t& new_size2)
{
    new_size1 = 1;
    new_size2 = 1;
    size_t stop_at = (size_t)sqrt(old_size) + 1;
    for (size_t i = 1; i<stop_at; i++)
    {
        if ( old_size % i == 0 )
        {
            new_size1 = i;
            new_size2 = old_size / i;
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
T** twoDimensionify(T* p_old_array, const size_t old_size)
{
    size_t new_size1=1, new_size2=1, old_i=0;
    calc_new_sizes(old_size, new_size1, new_size2);
    T** returnValue = new T*[new_size1];
    for (size_t i=0; i<new_size1; i++)
    {
        returnValue[i] = new T[new_size2];
        for (size_t j=0; j<new_size2; j++)
        {
            returnValue[i][j] = p_old_array[old_i];
            old_i++;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}

int main()
{
    size_t old_size=20, new_size1=0, new_size2=0;
    calc_new_sizes(old_size, new_size1, new_size2);
    std::cout << "From " << old_size << " to " << new_size1 << "x" << new_size2 << std::endl;

    int old_array[20] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
    int **new_array = twoDimensionify<int>(old_array, 20);
    for (size_t i=0; i<new_size1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<new_size2; j++)
        {
            std::cout << "new array[" << i << "," << j << "] = " << new_array[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Clean up my memory.  This is C++ afterall.
    for (size_t i=0; i<new_size1; i++)
    {
       delete [](new_array[i]);
    }
    delete []new_array;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like this.  Though with some challenges accessing a proper compiler I can't verify...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

void calc_new_sizes(const size_t old_size, size_t& new_size1, size_t& new_size2)
{
    new_size1 = 1;
    new_size2 = 1;
    size_t stop_at = (size_t)sqrt(old_size) + 1;
    for (size_t i = 1; i<stop_at; i++)
    {
        if ( old_size % i == 0 )
        {
            new_size1 = i;
            new_size2 = old_size / i;
        }
    }
}


template <class T, size_t new_size_1, size_t new_size_2, size_t old_size>
std::array<new_size_1, std::array<T, new_size_2>> twoDimensionify(std::array<T, old_size> p_input)
{
    std::array<new_size_1, std::array<T, new_size_2>> returnValue;
    int old_i = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<new_size_1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<new_size_2; j++)
        {
            returnValue[i][j] = p_input[old_i];
            old_i++;
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}

int main()
{
    size_t old_size=20, new_size1=0, new_size2=0;
    calc_new_sizes(old_size, new_size1, new_size2);
    std::cout << "From " << old_size << " to " << new_size1 << "x" << new_size2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this :)! Just one more question.. The results show: Rows: 1, Columns: 62017 ... So what is the number of blocks I can split this into? It still wouldn't be an even number, will it?

Comment: @user1582478 think about your mathematical factors.  As pointed out, 62017 I believe is a prime number, so it's only factors are 1x62017 and that's your only choice.  Something like 20 would have 1x20, 2x10, and 4x5.  You might actually be asking a different questions than I though where you would have empty cells in the last row, ex: rows of 1000 using 63 of them, in the last row only 17 of the 1000 are used.  Is that what your asking for?

Comment: Hey, I think I get what you mean. Basically, I'm doing signal processing and sound.. And I need to split the massive sample into equal blocks so then I can analyse them, but, with the data sizes I get, it's hard to even begin to think what I could split the blocks into. I created an algorithm that splited a 512*512 vector into blocks of 16*16 blocks etc but obviously, I wouldn't be able to use that code on this project. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1582478 I would recommend using a fixed size for different types.  For instance with audio you'll run into certain codecs always use the same bytes per frame, so you'll want to use a multiple of that.

Comment: Sorry that has confused me, what do mean by types? So I should multiply the number I have to allow for all of the frames? But, dividing the sample into blocks is still a real issue. Am I missing the point?

Comment: Sorry again.. Could this work: N = 30 (600 samples), M = 10 (200 samples)

Comment: @Phorce - Yes, that one looks a lot better